# How to enable CORS for Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, cors, ionic-framework, google-places-api, google-places

I have tried everything possible to make my app work without the need for the "Enable CORS extension for Chrome". I followed the steps on Google's official website which talks of authtokens, tried using every different key, but nothing works. I get the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=MyKey&location=33.854546,-84.35870369999999&types=restaurant&rankby=distance.` No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://localhost:8100` is therefore not allowed access.

Is it even possible to access Google Places API from inside an app, without the CORS extension for Chrome?

Comment: Use the Javascript API and Places Service to access the Places API from the frontend.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of CORS, you can use JSONP to accomplish your task.

Please read the following to get started: [**Link1**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), [**Link2**](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)

Comment: Which is useless if you need POST request

Comment: JSONP is unsafe and I believe it's even blocked by Google API, it's not recommended.
Use google api client library instead