# Not able to get the response in my ember app for google place api

Tags: ember.js, cors, google-places-api, google-places

I am sending the request to google place api. I am getting  an error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am using an api key which I created for testing purpose.I enabled google place web service api.I inserted the the url "http://localhost:4200" while generating the api.I am not sure where I am going wrong.Please suggest how should I make this correct and save the reponse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS for Google Places API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178359/how-to-enable-cors-for-google-places-api)

Comment: You need to configure CSP for your app, see [the README of ember-cli-content-security-policy](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy#example).